# How can I get the right row from the XP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a MySQL database that has a list of levels (1-10) and has a XP_NEEDED column, I already have a number and I want to find the level from that number (the number is an XP), I know how to do this in the way below...

```
Example (Short):
if ($xpLookingFor >= 100 && $xpLookingFor < 200) // Checks if not high as level 2 {
    return '1'; // Would be returning Level1
}
else if ($xpLookingFor >= 200 && $xpLookingFor < 300) // Checks if not high as level 3 {
    return '2'; // Would be returning Level2
}
```

So it checks if its higher than the current level but not as high as the level aboves xp_needed, if its as high as the next level the next if statement will handle it.

But this way has a lot of code that could possibly be shortened, what is the best way to do this? is there a built in mysql feature for this?

Comment: You have a [number of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6276855/thegod39) on here that are answered well but not marked as resolved. Please start marking answers as correct when applicable, otherwise you have many people helping you without giving anything in return. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unaware how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if this is what you need question is not too clear.

```
<?php
function getLevel($xp, $maxLevel) {
    for($check = 1; $check < $maxLevel; $check++)
        if ($xp >= ($check*100) AND $xp < ($check*100)+100) return $check;
    return $maxLevel;
}

//Param #1 is the xp level and #2 is the max level
echo getLevel(503, 10); // returns 5
echo getLevel(123, 10); //returns 1
echo getLevel(1405, 20); //returns 14
echo getLevel(1405, 10); //returns 10
?>
```

Comment: Good solution +1, the only issue is if each level isn't a multiple of 100, this wouldn't work, but it's unclear from the question if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `elseif`, the first part of the if isn't needed, you could stack them something like this.

```
function getLevel($xpLookingFor){
    if ($xpLookingFor < 100){
        return 0;
    }
    else if ($xpLookingFor < 200){
        return 1;
    }
    else if ($xpLookingFor < 300){
        return 2;
    }
    else if ($xpLookingFor < 375){
        return 3;
    }
    else if ($xpLookingFor < 400){
        return 4;
    }
    else {
        return 'MAX!';
    }
}
```

[See example on IdeOne](https://ideone.com/jlKQkG)